# How to set a custom theme for a popUp menu from Java in Android?

Tags: java, android

I've read in the android documentation that there is a way to doing it from the popup constructor

PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor, int gravity, int popupStyleAttr, int popupStyleRes)
Constructor to create a new popup menu with a specific style, but I can´t understand how the syntax would be

I'm trying to do something like this [customPopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4U4K.jpg)

I'm kinda new in this area of programming, maybe is a obvious answer but i can´t figured out the way. Sorry in advanced for my english

Comment: What about a new Fragment with CardView and 4 ImageViews and transparent background? Would it solve your Problem?

Comment: mmmh, the menu should be atached to a button that is in a recyclerview, so i don't know exactly how to do it